# Is $x^4+4$ an irreducible polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

We know that $p(x)=x^4-4=(x^2-2)(x^2+2)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ even not having roots there.

What about $q(x)=x^4+4\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$? Again, no roots.

Comment: Notice that $x^4 + 4 = (x^2+2)^2 - (2x)^2$.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray}x^4+4&=&(x^2+2i)\cdot (x^2-2i)\\ &=& (x-(1-i))\cdot (x+(1-i))\cdot (x-(1+i))\cdot(x+(1+i)) \\
&=& ((x-1)+i)\cdot ((x-1)-i)\cdot((x+1)-i)\cdot((x+1)+i) \\
&=& ((x-1)^2+1)\cdot((x+1)^2+1).\end{eqnarray}$$

Reducible.

Comment: Great and thanks. Just one more question: is there some irreducibility criterion to answer this without trying to factor it?

Comment: @Sigur: sometimes you can use Eisenstein's criterion, but it is generally a hard problem.

Comment: @akkkk, it does not apply here. Any else?

Comment: @Sigur: no general one, because that would probably give you an efficient algorithm for prime factorization.

Comment: I edited your answer so that it wasn't all on one line.

Comment: @akkkk Actually there is a polynomial time algorithm for factorizing polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$. Search for the LLL algorithm

Comment: @Sigur You can also try using substitutions such as $x= y+1$ and trying Eisenstein on that... I believe there is actually an algorithm for determining which substitution you need to make, if it's gonna work.

Answer (score 10):

$x^4+4 \cdot 1^4= x^4+ 2 \cdot 2 \cdot x^2+2^2 - (2x)^2$

Which is well known identity called [Sophie Germain](http://aleph.straylight.co.uk/sophie.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

As Berci showed, this polynomial is indeed reducible over the rationals.
One way to see it is to calculate its roots explicitly:
$$x^4+4=0 \leftrightarrow x^2 = \pm 2i \leftrightarrow x = \pm \sqrt{2} (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)) \vee x = \pm  i\sqrt{2} (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)) $$
Or:
$$x = \pm 1 \pm i$$
And since those roots are proper complex number in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, you can pair $1+i$ with $\overline{1+i}=1-i$ and $-1+i$ with $\overline{-1+i} = -1-i$ and obtain the factorization $(x^2 - 2x + 2)(x^2 + 2x +2)$ (if $\alpha$ is a proper complex root of $p \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, then $\overline{\alpha}$ is another root, and $(x-\alpha)(x-\overline{\alpha}) = (x^2-2Re(\alpha) + |\alpha|^2)$ divides $p$.

Comment: Amazing how a simple question can produce many interesting facts.

Answer (score 6):

$$X^4+4=X^4+4X^2+4-4X^2 =(X^2+2)^2-(2X)^2 \,.$$

Answer (score 3):

One may use the same version of completing the square that proves that $x+\dfrac1x \ge 2$ when $x>0$:

$$
x+\frac1x = \left(x-2+\frac1x\right)+2 = \left(\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2+2.
$$

Similarly
$$
x^4+4 = \left( x^4 +4x^2 + 4 \right) - 4x^2 = \left(x^2+2\right)^2 - (2x)^2
$$
then factor that as a difference of two squares.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Sophie Germain's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain) result(don't you think her name is worth mentioning here). If this was Gauss's result, someone would have mention the name Gauss. But this is not.

> [Sophie Germain Identity](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Sophie_Germain_Identity)
>   \begin{align}
> x^4+4y^4= (x^{2}+2y^{2}-2xy)(x^{2}+2y^{2}+2xy)\tag{1}
> \end{align}

To answer the question,

Put $y=1$ in $(1)$. Thus

$$x^4+4= (x^{2}+2-2x)(x^{2}+2+2x)$$

Hence $q(x)$ reducible over $\Bbb Q[x]$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/253765/31682 below.

Comment: Oh, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks!