# Factoring a complex polynomial

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Factorize the polynomial :

$$ p(x) = x^{5} - x^{4}+ 4x - 4 $$

In real factors in the lowest degree possible.

So in previous questions I have been given at least one rot so that I can factorize it with polynomial division. But how do I do now?

Comment: I love the first step of the answer, but the answer should be 
$$(x-1)(x^{2} + 2x +2)(x^{2} + 2x +2)$$ How does the two last parenthesis develop.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/253758/11619). See the answer by N.S. in particular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$x^5-x^4+4x-4=x^4(x-1)+4(x-1)=(x-1)(x^4+4)$$

Again, 
$$x^4+4=(x^2)^2+2^2=(x^2+2)^2-2\cdot x^2\cdot 2=(x^2+2)^2-(2x)^2$$

Comment: It seems worth pointing out that the factor of $x=1$ is the simplest candidate consistent with the Rational Root theorem, and so immediately pops up in that approach. (Though it's also obvious here since the coefficients sum to 0).

Comment: @Semiclassical I love the first step of the answer, but the answer should be 
$$(x-1)(x^{2} + 2x +2)(x^{2} + 2x +2)$$ How does the two last parenthesis develop.

Comment: One of those factors should be $x^2-2x+2$. And it follows directly from the last expression of the answer above, if we recognize it as a difference of squares. @Ara

Comment: My bad, of course it should be as you said. :/ 
Salute to you :) Many thanks!